# Creating an API endpoint for creating a profile in prisma

Tags: forms, next.js, prisma, tsx, zod

I can't find out how to create an API for adding a model in a prisma database from a form,  I have tried several times and I just don't know what to do. By the way, I am new to this. I don't know how to start. I asked ChatGPT many times, but it gave me code mostly for the page router. I doesn't know what the app router is

I tried this code that ChatGPT gave me:

```js
// pages/api/profiles/create.ts
import { withApiAuthRequired } from '@clerk/nextjs/api';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method Not Allowed' });
  }

  try {
    // Access and process the data sent in the POST request body
    const { userId, fullName, email, /* other fields */ } = req.body;

    // Example: Create a profile in the database using Prisma
    const newProfile = await prisma.profile.create({
      data: {
        userId,
        fullName,
        email,
        // ... other fields
      },
    });

    return res.status(201).json(newProfile);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not create profile' });
  }
};

export default withApiAuthRequired(handler);
```

It gave code for page router, but I am on the app router
Here is my code on my app/create-profile/page.tsx:

```js
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import { formSchema } from "@/app/create-profile/constants";
import { UploadDropzone } from "@/app/utils/uploadthing";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";
import { useAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
const ProfileForm = () => {
  const { userId } = useAuth();
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      fullName: "",
      email: "",
      src: "",
      Education: "",
      PastPosition: "",
      Skills: "",
      TechStack: "",
      AboutMe: "",
      Country: "",
      LinkedIn: "",
      GitHub: "",
      Instagram: "",
      Twitter: "",
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    if (userId) {
      if (values.LinkedIn) {
        await prismadb.profile.create({
          data: {
            userId: userId,
            fullName: values.fullName,
            email: values.email,
            age: values.age,
            src: values.src,
            Education: values.Education,
            PastPosition: values.PastPosition,
            Skills: values.Skills,
            TechStack: values.TechStack,
            AboutMe: values.AboutMe,
            Country: values.Country,
            LinkedIn: values.LinkedIn,
            Github: values.GitHub,
            Instagram: values.Instagram,
            Twitter: values.Twitter,
          },
        });
      }
    } else {
      // Handle the case when userId is null or undefined
      console.error("User ID is null or undefined.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <UploadDropzone
        endpoint="imageUploader"
        className="w-[350px] block m-auto mt-2 bg-white border-black border-4 border-solid ut-label:text-black ut-button:bg-black ut-button:text-white ut-button:block ut-button:m-auto"
        onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
          form.setValue("src", String(res[0].url));
          console.log(form.getValues("src"));
        }}
        onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
          // Do something with the error.
          alert(`ERROR! ${error.message}`);
        }}
      />
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormField
            name="fullName"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Full Name" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="age"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Age</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Age" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="email"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="johndoe@gmail.com"
                    {...field}
                    type="email"
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Education"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Education</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="Bacherlor's in Computer Science"
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="PastPosition"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Job</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="Software Engineer, Google / Unemployed"
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Skills"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Skills</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="FullStack development, mobile development"
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Country"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Place of living</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="LA,CAL,USA" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="TechStack"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>TechStack</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="Python,JavaScript,NextJS, TailwindCSS ..."
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-zinc-800">About You</h1>
          <Separator className="h-1 bg-zinc-800 w-[500px] block m-auto my-3" />

          <FormField
            name="AboutMe"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormControl>
                  <Textarea
                    rows={4}
                    placeholder="I first started programming when I was 12..."
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>required</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-zinc-800">
            Your Social Media
          </h1>
          <Separator className="h-1 bg-zinc-800 w-[500px] block m-auto my-3" />
          <FormField
            name="LinkedIn"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout LinkedIn</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="https://linkedin.com/you" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>required</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="GitHub"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout GitHub</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="https://github.com/you" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Instagram"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout Instagram</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="https://instagram.com/you" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Twitter"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout Twitter/X</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="https://twitter.com/you" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <Button type="submit" className="block m-auto my-3">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileForm;
```